# Find data() key-value pairs for every element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-data

What is the best way to view all jQuery `data` key-value pairs across *every* element (in jQuery 2.x)?

A selection-oriented approach ( e.g. `$('*').data()` ) obviously does not work, because the return value is tied to a single element.

I know that I can iterate over every element, checking each for data:

```
var allData = [];
$('html *').each(function() {
    if($.hasData(this)) {
        allData.push({ el: this, data: $(this).data() })
    }
})
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jwhitfieldseed/A5WaA/)

This does produce the expected output, but iterating over each possible data key feels like a backwards approach to this problem.

Is there some way to find all element data directly?

N.B. I'm interested for debugging, not production code.

Comment: jQuery creates an internal cache variable with the data. The only way I could see this happen is if you can access the cache variable.

Comment: Yep. I have read some of the source, which appears to hide the cache var, but I hoped that somebody may know better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could select every element within the body with `$("body *")` and apply jQuery's [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to it. Working example:

```
var $elementsContainingData $("body *").filter(function() {
    if($.hasData(this)) return this;  
});
console.log($elementsContainingData);
```

**Edit**

As @spokey mentioned before, there's an internal variable named "cache" within the jQuery object: `$.cache`.

This variable consists of a bunch of objects which contain keys like "data" or "events":

```
5: Object
data: Object
events: Object
handle: function (a){return typeof m===K||a&&m.event.triggered===a.type?void     0:m.event.dispatch.apply(k.elem,arguments)}
__proto__: Object
```

You can iterate through that object and filter for the data:

```
var filteredCache = $.each($.cache,function() {
        if(typeof this["data"] === "object") return this;
    });
```

Here's an working example plus a function to merge that stuff into a single and more handy object consisting only of dataKey => dataValue pairings: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Whre/tNaf4/1/)

**Edit**

As mentioned in comments this solution does not work in jQuery version 2.x since `$.cache` is deprecated.

My last suggestion is creating a hook for jQuerys data function in order to extend an own object`$.dataCache = {};` each time `data()` is called.
Extending, replacing or adding jQuerys functions is done by accessing `$.fn.functionName`:

```
$.fn.data = function(fn,hook) {
    return function() {
        hook.apply(this,arguments);
        return fn.apply(this,arguments);
    }
}($.fn.data,function(key,value) {
    var objReturn = {};
    objReturn[key] = value;
    $.extend($.dataCache,objReturn);
});
```

This also works great in jQuery version 2: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Whre/Z64Kv/9/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This answers something different - 'find all the elements with jQuery data', not 'find all of the data without iterating over every element'. BTW, you could use `return $.hasData(this)` to be more concise.

Comment: As @spokey mentioned before, there's an internal variable named "cache" within the jQuery object: `$.cache`.

This variable consists of a bunch of objects which contain keys like "data" or "events".

See my initial posting for more details and a fiddle.

Comment: `$.cache` in present in jQuery 1.x, but it appears to have been deprecated in 2.x. +1 though, thanks. This would certainly be the answer for 1.x.

Comment: I posted another solution also working in jQuery 2.x. It's done by hooking into the data() function.

Comment: That looks ace. One comment - duplicate keys over different elements will be overwritten. Is there some way of identifying which element the k/v pairs belong to?

Comment: You could use nested objects.
If I add

        if(typeof $.dataCache[this.selector] !== "object") { $.dataCache[this.selector] = {}; }
        $.extend($.dataCache[this.selector],objReturn);

the result is sorted by the selector. That means you have an object like { p : { foo : "bar", apple: "banana" } } if you use $("p").data() and an object like { div:nth-child(1) { ... } } if you select $("div:nth-child(1)").data(). Then you can access it via $.dataCache["p"]["foo"] etc.